# How to add custom portlet in Control Panel section

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, control-panel

How can I add a custom portlet to the `Portal` section of the Control Panel, as shown in the following figure:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

1. In your portlet's `liferay-portlet.xml` (you can check the [DTD](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/definitions/liferay-portlet-app_6_1_0.dtd#L338) of this xml for more information on other tags) include two tags in your `<portlet>` tag as shown:

   ```html
   <portlet>
       <portlet-name>MyCustomPortlet</portlet-name>
       <icon>/mycustom.png</icon>
       <!--
           These are the two entries which are required for the portlet
           to appear in the control panel
       -->
       <!--
           Set the control-panel-entry-category value to "my", "content",
           "portal" or "server" to make this portlet available in the
           Control Panel under that category.
       -->
       <control-panel-entry-category>portal</control-panel-entry-category>

       <!--
          Set the control-panel-entry-weight value to a double number
          to control the position of the entry within its Control Panel
          category. Higher values mean that the entry will appear lower
          in the Control Panel menu.
       -->
       <control-panel-entry-weight>100</control-panel-entry-weight>

       <instanceable>false</instanceable>
       <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
       <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/main.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
       <css-class-wrapper>mycustomportlet-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
   </portlet>
   ```
2. Also, if you don't want your portlet to appear in the `Add Menu` so that it is not put on other pages, then in your `liferay-display.xml` you can include:

   ```html
   <display>
       <category name="category.hidden">
           <!--
              Adding your portlet to the hidden category would not display
              the portlet in the ADD Menu on the top-left-hand corner
           -->
           <portlet id="MyCustomPortlet"></portlet>
       </category>
   </display>
   ```
3. Build and deploy your portlet and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the Answer by Prakash K, ajaxable and instanciable should be false.