# Configuring Liferay Service Plugin

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6, spring-portlet-mvc

I have created a liferay service using the Service Builder framework. This service is used to fetch content from an external source, and once it is deployed, it is available to all portlets.

Is there a way to add configurations to plugins of this type ? In normal portlets, you can add a configurations page, which allows you to change the portlet's preferences in runtime. In this type of plugin, there is only one instance, and it is not meant to be dragged to pages like normal portlets so how would one add configurations to such plugin ?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Do you require editing this configuration from a UI (Like a control panel or portlet Setting), or is it OK to edit config by editing a property in a text file ?

Comment: it is ok to edit in a text file, the only thing i need is to be able to do it in runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such settings is the default behaviour to use the "Control Panel".

Create a separate portlet in the same project and put it only to "Control Panel".

See this link for more details: [How to add custom portlet in Control Panel section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066674/how-to-add-custom-portlet-in-control-panel-section)